# Volume scatter shader causes black spots

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, shaders, volumetrics

I am following Andrew price's video on making clouds but my clouds are rendering with black spots on them. I have tried turning up the maximum transparency value under light paths but there is no difference between 50 and 200.

[image]

What could be causing this?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

These are caused by self-intersecting bits of the cloud particles showing the backsides of faces to the outside world:

[image]

Rays going through the back of a face don't count as going into the volume, and so appear mostly transparent.

To fix this you have a couple options:

- Lighten up on the displacement to avoid such intersections:

  [image]
- Or add a remesh modifier (and optionally a decimate modifier to keep the vertex count down)

  [image]

Comment: Ah, thanks. Lowering the displacement strength worked perfect.